# Obtaining records where a certain condition is satisfied with two has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through, has-many

Let's say I have 3 models in my Rails app... Establishment, WasteType and EstablishmentWaste... My problem is that I want to **get all establishments associated with a certain wastetype**. This normally would be done with `Establishment.where(waste_type_id: some_number)`, the problem is that **Establishment has many WasteType and vice versa**, and the association is made through a third party...

Any help?

**Classes and data model below**

[image]

**Establishment**

```
class Establishment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

    has_many :containers
    has_many :establishment_wastes
    has_many :waste_types, through: :establishment_wastes, :foreign_key => 'establishment_id'

  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
end
```

**WasteType**

```
class WasteType < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :containers
    has_many :establishment_wastes
    has_many :establishments, through: :establishment_wastes, :foreign_key => 'waste_type_id'

end
```

**EstablishmentWaste**

```
class EstablishmentWaste < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :establishment, :foreign_key => 'establishment_id' 
    belongs_to :waste_type, :foreign_key => 'waste_type_id'

end
```

So the data model would be like these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EstablishmentWaste` is a join table in this case so the query should be.

```
Establishment
 .joins(:establishment_wastes)
 .where('establishment_wastes.waste_type_id = ?', some_number)
```

**Quick tip!** You do not need to assign `:foreign_key => 'establishment_id'` since it is default Rails behavior to assign a foreign key to `model_id`.